# Передать данные из table в контроллер без JS (по нажатию submit)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, submit

Нужно передать данные из таблицы в составе модели.

Table во View (упрощенно):

```
<table id="ProjectsListBody">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td name="Projects[0].Number"><input type="hidden" value="266">abc123</td>
         <td name="Projects[0].Name" id="Projects_[0]__Name">Text1</td></tr>
       <tr>
         <td name="Projects[1].Number"><input type="hidden" value="216">der456</td>
         <td name="Projects[1].Name" id="Projects_[1]__Name">Text2</td></tr>
       <tr>
         <td name="Projects[2].Number"><input type="hidden" value="2884">ret789</td>
         <td name="Projects[2].Name" id="Projects_[2]__Name">Text3</td></tr>          
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Модель (упрощенно):

```
 public class ProjectsListModel
    { 
        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }      
        public List<ProjectsListMemberDetails> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

И сам лист Projects:

```
public class ProjectsListMemberDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }         
        public string Number { get; set; }        
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть submit:

```
<button type="submit">Preview</button>
```

Таблица и кнопка находятся в блоке using:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectsListPreview", "Reports", FormMethod.Post))
```

Контроллер:

```
 [HttpPost]
   public FileContentResult ProjectsListPreview(ProjectsListModel model)
   {
       return null;
   }
```

Вопрос: как связать данные из таблицы с моделью, чтобы в контроллер приходил необходимый массив `List<ProjectsListMemberDetails> Projects`? (привязки по имени оказалось недостаточно, лист приходит пустой; а также как связать value в input с ID элементов в Projects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Упрощенно, вам нужно получить такой html для каждого элемента `ProjectsListMemberDetails`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Projects.Index" value="any_unique_string" />
<input type="text" name="Projects[any_unique_string].Id" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="Projects[any_unique_string].Number" value="266" />
<input type="text" name="Projects[any_unique_string].Name" value="Text1" />
```

Где `any_unique_string` любой уникальный в рамках одной `form` строковый литерал. Это могут быть как числа `0, 1, 2, ...`, так и произвольные строки `a, ab, abc, ...`

Comment: Да, принцип ясен если это input, но если это td?

Comment: Сделала, добавив между <td></td> input-ы для значений. Спасибо!

Comment: При отправке формы отправляются только значения определенных элементов http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp